# How to use Sessions in ASP vNext

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I use session variables in ASP MVC 6 ?

I couldn't find a working sample on how to store and use session variables . Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add package `"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta8"` to project.json and then `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;`

inside that namespace you have extension methods for context.

you also need to use it with DI on `Startup.cs`  :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession();
    }
```

Here's a sample controller :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace MvcWebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt("myVar", 35);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding the project nuget references and adding the session in the service, I'm getting the following error : `Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSession' and no extension method 'AddSession' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Beta 8 renames the Context property to HttpContext (in line with MVC 5)

Comment: Hi @ChristopherHackett do you have some links which points to this renames?

Comment: Sure @neel - Documented in this ticket for the MVC repo https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3165

Answer (score 1):

there is a sample on the session repo  on github: https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/release

And you can access to the session by the `Controler's Session` property

Comment: I tried it but i get this error : 500 Internal Server Error
System.ArgumentException
ISessionStore must be specified.

Comment: If i enable app.UseInMemorySession();  , I get another error 500 Internal Server Error
System.Exception
TODO: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.Session.DistributedSessionStore'.

Comment: Did you enable caching ? the sample use Redis cache

Comment: I didn't enable caching .   I tried adding RedisCache package and it still didn't work .

Comment: You must enable caching

Comment: How do i enable caching ?

Comment: `services.AddCaching()`

Comment: What nuget package do i need to add... cuz i get this error : CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddCaching' and no extension method 'AddCaching' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) website.ASP.NET 5.0 Startup.cs 34

Comment: I managed to do it . It was  services.AddCachingServices();
      services.AddSessionServices();

Comment: @FAndrei: Thanks. I also had a problem with MVC6 RC after adding app.UseSession() (hard crash). Adding  services.AddSessionServices(); and services.AddCaching(); in startup.cs solved the problem.